# How to check if a variable has "mysqli" or "mariadb" value

Tags: bash

I have the following piece of a script:

```
set ${DB_TYPE:='mysqli'}

echo $DB_TYPE

if [  $DB_TYPE -eq "mysqli"  -o  $DB_TYPE -eq "mariadb"  ]; then
      #Do some stuff
else
  echo >&2 "This database type is not supported"
   echo >&2 "Did you forget to -e DB_TYPE='mysqli' ^OR^ -e DB_TYPE='mariadb' ?"
  exit 1
fi
```

But this piece of script somehow fails on:

```
if [  $DB_TYPE -eq "mysqli"  -o  $DB_TYPE -eq "mariadb"  ]; then
```

So how can I compare if $DB_TYPE id either "mysqli" or "mariadb"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be useful to know *how* it fails but there are a few things obviously wrong with the following:

```
if [  $DB_TYPE -eq "mysqli"  -o  $DB_TYPE -eq "mariadb"  ]; then
```

- variables are unquoted (dangerous within `[`)
- `-eq` is for comparing integers, `=` should be used for strings (see [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/143793/67817) for detailed discussion of the difference)

As you've tagged [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) then you should be aware of the improved `[[` which allows you to write this:

```
if [[ $DB_TYPE = mysqli || $DB_TYPE = mariadb ]]; then
```

Within `[[` you don't need to quote your variables and you can use `||` as a logical *or*.

You might also consider using this:

```
case $DB_TYPE in
    mysqli|mariadb)
        # do one thing
        ;;
    *)
        # do other stuff
        ;;
esac
```

Answer (score 2):

`-eq` means equals to. It is for integer numbers, not strings. For strings use `=`, like:

```
if [ "$DB_TYPE" = "mysqli" ] || [ "$DB_TYPE" = "mariadb" ]; then
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a recent version of `bash`, you can use the extended regular expression matching built in via the `equal tilde (=~)` operator.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ "$DB_TYPE" =~ ^(mysqli|mariadb)$ ]]; then
```